# ruamel.yaml how to sort elements inside CommentedMap

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I want to load the YAML file, sort it by key and dump the file.

I have tried the solution given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40227545/1307905), but it is not working.

My YAML file:

```
devices:
#list of devices    #list of devices
  - hostName: testhb200
    hostNetwork: 192.178.101.0
    hostMask: 255.255.255.255
  - hostName: testha100
    hostNetwork: 192.178.225.12
    hostMask: 255.255.255.252
    hostGateway: 192.178.225.13
    hostIp: 192.168.225.14
    vendor: vendor
    model: qfx5200-
```

I am using the snippet below for loading YAML.

```
# YAML settings
class YamlUtil:
    logging.basicConfig(level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "INFO"))

    # YAML settings
    _yaml = YAML(typ="rt")
    _yaml.default_flow_style = False
    _yaml.explicit_start = False
    _yaml.preserve_quotes = True
    _yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
    _yaml.Representer.add_representer(OrderedDict,
                                      _yaml.Representer.represent_dict)

    def __init__(self, yaml: YAML = _yaml):
        # Override default class yaml settings
        self.yaml = yaml

    def load_file(self, file):
        with open(file, "r") as f:
            return self.yaml.load(f)

    def dump_file(self, data, file):
        with open(file, "w") as f:
            self.yaml.dump(data, f)
```

the following snippet works for sorting

```
    yml = YamlUtil().load_file(args.input)
    yml['devices'].sort(lambda x: x['hostName'])
    YamlUtil().dump_file(yml, args.output)
```

But how do I make it a generic sorting?

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate what is not working, but you probably are not using Python 2.7, which the linked answer expects as that
would load `ruamel.ordereddict`, and give `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap` the `.sort()` method.

When working with newer python versions, just remove the special handling for `CommentedMap`:

```
import sys
import pathlib
from collections import OrderedDict
import ruamel.yaml
YAML = ruamel.yaml.YAML
CM = ruamel.yaml.CommentedMap


# YAML settings
class YamlUtil:
    # logging.basicConfig(level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "INFO"))

    # YAML settings
    _yaml = YAML(typ="rt")
    _yaml.default_flow_style = False
    _yaml.explicit_start = False
    _yaml.preserve_quotes = True
    _yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
    _yaml.Representer.add_representer(OrderedDict, _yaml.Representer.represent_dict)

    def __init__(self, yaml: YAML = _yaml):
        # Override default class yaml settings
        self.yaml = yaml

    def load_file(self, path):
        return self.yaml.load(path)

    def dump_file(self, data, path):
        self.yaml.dump(data, path)


def rec_sort(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        res = ruamel.yaml.CommentedMap()
        for k in sorted(d.keys()):
            res[k] = rec_sort(d[k])
        return res
    if isinstance(d, list):
        for idx, elem in enumerate(d):
            d[idx] = rec_sort(elem)
    return d

data = YamlUtil().load_file(pathlib.Path('input.yaml'))
data = rec_sort(data)
YamlUtil().dump_file(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
devices:
#list of devices    #list of devices
  - hostMask: 255.255.255.255
    hostName: testhb200
    hostNetwork: 192.178.101.0
  - hostGateway: 192.178.225.13
    hostIp: 192.168.225.14
    hostMask: 255.255.255.252
    hostName: testha100
    hostNetwork: 192.178.225.12
    model: qfx5200-
    vendor: vendor
```