# ruamel.yaml dump contains "..."

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I need to sort the contents of a YAML file, and I'm learning ruamel.yaml to do this.

Given this file `example.yml`:

```yaml
---
- job:
    name: this is the job name
```

And this Python program:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()  # defaults to round-trip

# Read YAML file
with open('example.yml', 'r') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)

yaml.dump(data[0]['job']['name'], sys.stdout)
```

I get the job name, but I also get an extra line with `...`:

```
$ python example.py
this is the job name
...
$
```

I wasn't expecting to see the `...` so I'm a tad confused. Where is it coming from and why?

Comment: You are dumping a YAML document consisting of a single non-scalar value. That is not often done and ruamel.yaml behaves a bit differently in that case based on code inherited from PyYAML, which might not be necessary for this particular case. You could test `if isinstance(data[0]['job']['name'], str):` and then print.

Comment: The recommended file extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` for over 15 years. the YML file format is an XML derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [YAML boundary marker.](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/current.html#document%20boundary%20marker/)

It's not entirely clear what exactly you are hoping to produce here. If you don't specifically want a YAML document on output, probably just print the thing. I'm guessing you are in the middle of debugging something, because this seems unrelated to the actual task you claim to be working on.

If you want to sort the YAML file internally, the [PyYAML module](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) does that by default. If you need it for Ruamel specifically, [ruamel.yaml equivalent of sort_keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226610/ruamel-yaml-equivalent-of-sort-keys) has a solution.